# How to know in which file that defined a js global var in chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mootools, google-chrome-devtools

How to find out which file and line a variable was defined in using google chrome console?

For example, the variable `Native` (from MooTools) has been defined in global scope. I want to know in which file that defined this variable using google chrome console.

Comment: It looks like you are just asking someone to search for something in [a file](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.5/mootools.js)? How is that a programming problem? How was that useful for 2 people? What is going on?

Comment: @Esailija in chrome console, not just for this time or for mootools.

Comment: If your question is "How to search which file a variable was defined in using chrome console" your question needs a serious edit, because right now you are just outsourcing people to do a `Ctrl+F` search in a file...

Comment: @Esailija I'm not good in English, could you helep me editing the question?

Comment: @Esailija Searching in a file isn't a suitable answer when the variable name is something like a single letter where searching for that letter would return thousands of results.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Using chrome :

1. Open the Web Inspector
2. Show the console and check if the var you're searching for exists (ex : Native <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
3. Click on the Resources panel
4. Enter `Native=`, `var Native` or `Native =` in the top right search field
5. You've got your result !

Here, there's only one result for the `Native=` search. The result is automatically highlighted, and the corresponding file opened. In my example, you can see the `Native` declaration was in `mootools.core.js`, line 12.

[image: Got it !]

**EDIT: March 2015** (thanks to [TML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644937/how-to-know-in-which-file-that-defined-a-js-global-var-in-chrome-console/12276821?noredirect=1#comment46025033_12276821))

The top right search field doesn't exist anymore, in latest Chrome versions.
Instead of, click on `Show drawer` in the top right corner (or hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>), and select the `Search` tab that just appeared in the bottom of your screen:

[image]

**EDIT: November 2015** (thanks [tzvi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644937/how-to-know-in-which-file-that-defined-a-js-global-var-in-chrome-console/12276821?noredirect=1#comment55007385_12276821))

You now need to use the three-dot button in the top right corner to find a `Search all files` option.

[image]

Comment: this is the only way for now :(

Comment: As of March 2015, this "Search" box is [not visible](http://imgur.com/09ss5CR) on the Resources tab of Chrome Developer Tools on OS X

Comment: Fantastic, @zessx! Thanks, and have some more +1's. :)

Comment: It has changed yet again >O
In Version 46.0.2490.52 (my current version) the search is moved somewhere else ( or removed ) i'm not really sure.

Comment: In version: 46.0.2490.80 use Ctrl+Shift F or use the menu in the upper right corner(those three vertical dots)->Search all files

Comment: Ugh. This is NOT useful if the variable name is something that returns thousands of results in a text search, like a single letter variable name!

Answer (score 2):

You may search for "var Native" in "Resources" (2nd) tab.

Function definition may be found from "Scope variables" block, from context menu, but
there's no such feature as "Find where this variable come from / was defined" in Chrome's WebInspector.

Comment: thank you, you are right. for now, there is no way to show the definition location.

Answer (score 1):

Native is defined in core.js line 437

```
var Native = this.Native = function(properties){
    return new Type(properties.name, properties.initialize);
};

Native.type = Type.type;

Native.implement = function(objects, methods){
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) objects[i].implement(methods);
    return Native;
};
```

https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Core/Core.js#L437

a quick file search for a = assignment is almost always the way to go