# Global variable origin

Tags: javascript

I have an interesting problem.
I've detected global variable `height` in my project.
Project has hundreds of files, so `height` variable occurs thousands of times.
Obviously, I had forgotten `var` operator somewhere.
How can I track this global variable origin?

**UPD:**
As I already said, variable occurs thousands of times.
And I don't really know how it can look like:

```
// forgotten var:
height = 'something';

// or forgotten comma
var a = 1,
    b = 2 
    height = 3;
```

So I definitely can not search for it manually.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You could investigate using the developer tools in chrome.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I wonder, how exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know in which file that defined a js global var in chrome console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644937/how-to-know-in-which-file-that-defined-a-js-global-var-in-chrome-console)

Comment: `grep -e 'height\s*='`?

Comment: Dear @Paulpro, thank you for suggestion. Your regexp found hundreds of matches, including `some_other_height` variables too. It's not really helpful.

Comment: If you have other vairables that end in height, you can add a boundary to make it to work for you: `grep -e '\bheight\s*=`. That should find everywhere `height` is assigned a value (which is what creates an implicit global). The forgotten `var` and forgotten comma options you posted wouldn't create a global, they would throw a `ReferenceError: height is not defined`.

Comment: @Paulpro this regexp definitely better, but it still found matches like `style.height`. Besides, no one said that after the variable was a "=" sign.

Comment: @legotin An equals sign is the only possible way to create a global variable accidentally. The only other way would be assigning it as a property of the global object, which would be pretty hard to do by accident.

Comment: There are also static tools, such as JSHINT, that can help.

Comment: You could try `grep -e '\(^\|\s\)height\s*='`. That should also filter out the `style.height` and such.

Comment: @Paulpro you're right. I've corrected cases where a it could occur.

Comment: @Paulpro you overdone with your last regexp, it finds nothing now :)

Comment: We might have differently flavours of `grep`. Maybe try: `grep -e '(^|\s)height\s*=` ?

Comment: It works! I found it! @Paulpro <3

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equals sign is the only possible way to create a global variable accidentally. The only other way would be assigning it as a property of the global object, which wouldn't likely be done by accident. Therefore you can search through your files for assignments to `height` using something like this:

```
grep -e '(^|\s)height\s*=' -R *
```

From those assignments you can determine where `height` gets created, and what scope it needs to be declared in.

By the way, in `'use strict';` mode, JavaScript would throw an error instead of creating an implicit global, which could be more desirable.