# Uncaught TypeError: URL is not a constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript

my code

```
let url = new URL('http://www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5');
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
console.log(searchParams.get('c'));  // outputs "m2-m3-m4-m5"
```

and the error

> Uncaught TypeError: URL is not a constructor

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you checked here ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I am using the latest version of chrome @Phill

Answer (score 8):

The only thing that would cause this error in **any** recent version of Chrome (at least since 2014's v32) would be if you had some other code that overwrote the `URL` symbol.

For example

```js
const URL = 'I am now a string'

// later...

let url = new URL('http://www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5');
```

If you're having trouble locating the code that's overwriting `URL`, you could start by simply adding

```js
console.log(URL)
```

to your code. The value logged may give you a hint. Otherwise, see this post ~ [How to know in which file that defined a js global var in chrome console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644937/how-to-know-in-which-file-that-defined-a-js-global-var-in-chrome-console)

---

Solutions:

- Try not to use global object names in your variables.
- Don't assign global variables if you can help it.

On that last note, you could avoid this problem like this

```js
(function() {
  const URL = 'I am a string but not window.URL'

  // later...

  let url = new window.URL('http://www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5');
  console.info(url.search)
})()
```

Comment: this code still gives me a error but it says window.URL is not a constructor

Comment: You must have some other code that is setting `URL` in the global / window scope. You should try and find it

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because `url.URL` is `undefined` (read more in this [comment](https://github.com/ConsenSys/armlet/issues/105#issuecomment-673060135)).