# pdf dowload using axios - vuejs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, axios, dompdf

ERROR getting ::

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: window.URL.createObjectURL is not a function at eval
>   unable to download pdf

My code:

```js
axios({                   
  url: url,                    
  method: 'GET',                    
  responseType: 'blob',                    
  headers: {                        
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +localStorage.getItem('token'),                        
  }                    
}).then((response) => {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));                    
  const link = document.createElement('a');                    
  link.href = url;                    
  link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf'); //or any other extension                    
  document.body.appendChild(link);                    
  link.click();                    
});
```

backend:

```php
public function getPDF(Request $request) {        
    $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML('<h1><center>Test</center></h1>');        
    return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');            
}
```

Comment: Browser and version please. You may be on an older version of chrome / ff / safari here.

Comment: Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit) chrome

Comment: Try `console.log(window.URL)` as the first line in your `then()` callback. What does that show in your console?

Comment: open your console and paste this:`window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob());` do you get the current URL as a blob?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: URL is not a constructor in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546419/uncaught-typeerror-url-is-not-a-constructor-in-javascript)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Uncaught TypeError: window.URL.createObjectURL is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:24
(anonymous) @ VM13866:1

Comment: @Phil while giving console.log(window.URL) i'getting a differnt url , not the one i'm using

Comment: What you just said doesn't really make sense. `console.log(window.URL)` **should** log something like _"ƒ URL() { [native code] }"_. Can you please show exactly what it **is** logging instead?

Comment: @Phil console.log(window.URL)
 http://192.168.1.105:8040
undefined

Comment: Please see the duplicate question. Something is overwriting `URL` in the `window` / global scope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189652/discussion-between-priya-and-phil).